# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is taking the time from my computer rather than UTC

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I was wondering how I can force UTC time or some MySQL standard time. I am using timestamp currently. I read that timestamp is suppose to be MySQL's standard time (like Unix time). However, when I used timestamp, it gave my my local machine's time rather than the UTC time (which I also read is the timezone timestamp is recorded in). I live in Australia so the UTC time is not the same time as on my local machine. But in the database it records it as my local machine's time

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id        int(11)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,
    date_updated    timestamp
                    NOT NULL
                    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

So I am wondering, how do I store a date and its time. I don't want to use Unix time

Comment: The `TIMESTAMP` column stores a unix timestamp (which is in UTC), but shows you a string based on your session time zone when you select it.

Comment: @Vatev is there limitations on timestamp datatype? I read that its bad to store unix timestamp in a database because an unsigned int can only go up so high

Comment: The values inside timestamp columns _are_ stored as UTC, the're converted to local time for display only.

Comment: Yes, there is a limitation. It is a 4 byte field with the usual range for a 4 byte unix timestamp (1970-2038). It might get upgraded in the future (the `DATETIME` type got an upgrade). You can use `DATETIME` (0000-9999 range), but that one doesn't have the automatic timezone conversion.